# Handle Angular Auth0 callback correctly with Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, flask, auth0

I am a first time user of Nginx and new to server configuration. I have an application working on my local machine with a Flask backend and Angular frontend, where Auth0 is located, but now trying to get it up and running on an Ubuntu server. I got the Angular front to show up on my server using Nginx, but after trying to log in the /callback route fails with a 404. I've looked at many similar questions and tutorials, but none are very clear or just mention a solution, but show no examples or code like the next link, or just say to use HashLocationStrategy, which I don't understand.

[How to setup Nginx with Auth0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143489/how-to-setup-nginx-with-auth0)

I have a CallbackComponent and a /callback route to it in app-routing.module.ts.  I have the allowed callback routes in Auth0 application configuration defined as:

```
http://my-ip-address/callback, http://localhost:4200/callback
```

and I have the Auth0 config in my app.module.ts file like this:

```
constructor() {
Auth0.configure({
  domain: 'domain-name',
  audience: 'audience-name',
  clientID: 'client-id',
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',
  scope: 'scope'
  });
}
```

I also tried changing the redirectUri to http://my-ip-address/callback, but nothing changed. My config.d file looks like this:

```
upstream gateway {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}
server {
        listen       80;
        root   /var/www/html;

        location / {
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header   Host             $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_pass http://gateway;          
    }
}
```

where gateway is my backend. Most of this is copied from tutorials and might not even be correct. I understand that Nginx has no idea what's going on inside Angular routing, but I don't know how to connect it all for it to work.

How to I handle the /callback route for Auth0 and Angular in Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it almost worked. My conf.d file, precisely this part:

`location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            }`

was correct. **However** in the /sites-enabled directory the default configuration file had a mistake in it like this `index.html=404` so it was searching for a page called 'index.html=404' in a cycle, which also gave 505 errors. Also, the redirectUri must be "http://my-ip-address/callback" in both the Auth0 dashboard configuration and wherever "Auth0.configure" function is called out.